# Why I am getting None when running this python code in Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def fizz_buzz(nums):

    if nums % 5 == 0 and nums % 3 == 0:
       print("FizzBuzz")
       
    elif nums % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz")

    elif nums % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz")

    elif nums % 3 != 0 and nums % 5 != 0:
        print(nums)
```

`print(fizz_buzz(30))`

Problems:

1. Why None is appearing in the output?
2. Can Anyone suggest what should I write in else statement? How I test else statement?

I am running this code in Google Colab.

Comment: Your function does not return anything (`None`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def fizz_buzz(nums):
    if nums % 5 == 0 and nums % 3 == 0:
        return "FizzBuzz"
       
    elif nums % 3 == 0:
        return "Fizz"

    elif nums % 5 == 0:
        return "Buzz"

    elif nums % 3 != 0 and nums % 5 != 0:
        return nums
```

Answer (score 0):

See, `fizz_buzz(30)` will return 30. But when you ***print*** the function itself, it's not worth anything. This is because the function doesn't return anything. A way to fix this would be to use the [`return`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/#:%7E:text=Itertools.Permutations()-,Python%20return%20statement,return%20statements%20are%20not%20executed.&text=Note%3A%20Return%20statement%20can%20not%20be%20used%20outside%20the%20function.) keyword.

You could try this:

```py
def fizz_buzz(nums):

    if nums % 5 == 0 and nums % 3 == 0:
       print("FizzBuzz")
       
    elif nums % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz")

    elif nums % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz")

    elif nums % 3 != 0 and nums % 5 != 0:
        print(nums)  

fizz_buzz(30)
```

## Or

```py
def fizz_buzz(nums):

    if nums % 5 == 0 and nums % 3 == 0:
       return "FizzBuzz"
       
    elif nums % 3 == 0:
        return "Fizz"

    elif nums % 5 == 0:
        return "Buzz"

    elif nums % 3 != 0 and nums % 5 != 0:
        return nums

fizz_buzz(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't return anything from the function, Just call the function with a parameter. An example is given below.

```
def fizz_buzz(nums):
    if nums % 5 == 0 and nums % 3 == 0:
        print("FizzBuzz")

    elif nums % 3 == 0:
        print("Fizz")

    elif nums % 5 == 0:
        print("Buzz")

    elif nums % 3 != 0 and nums % 5 != 0:
        print(nums)

fizz_buzz(30)
```

Or you can return something and print outside of the function. An example is given below.

```
def fizz_buzz(nums):
    if nums % 5 == 0 and nums % 3 == 0:
        return "FizzBuzz"

    elif nums % 3 == 0:
        return "Fizz"

    elif nums % 5 == 0:
        return "Buzz"

    elif nums % 3 != 0 and nums % 5 != 0:
        return nums

print(fizz_buzz(30))
```